# Partialview naming convention, long names bad?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, naming-conventions

Is it bad to have long names on `_Partialviews`?

Like `_Header_detachable_nav`, and that partial is gone have other partials `_Header_detachable_nav_cart`, 
`_Header_detachable_nav_navigation`

is this bad practice, does it matter at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underscore in the partial view helps to differentiate between full views and partial ones.

But more importantly, it prevents partial views from being loaded directly by their URL, which could provide some potentially ugly results! (Like no css, for starters.)

However It's not necessary to use an underscore.

And instead of having names like `_Header_detachable_nav_cart` instead you can use camelCase like for example `_HeaderDetachableNavCart`

Comment: Ok, thanks. In a way its not traditional camelCase because it starts with a Uppercase.